# How to test for whether a score for something is within x value of the score for something else?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, confidence-interval

If I were to issue a questionnaire that asks people to provide a particular, continuous numerical score to something (between 0-100) how would I statistically test whether the those scores were within x range of the scores that the same group later provided for something else?

Would using confidence intervals be sufficient?

For example, imagine that I have data at a 95% confidence level in which the scoring bounds for thing 1 are 45 to 65 and for thing 2 they are 71 to 86.

If I was testing for whether thing 1 would be within 5 points of thing 2 would this be sufficient to say it's statistically implausible?

Comment: I'm not sure that confidence intervals are the right tool for this. For clarification: are you primarily interested in comparing mean scores between thing 1 and thing 2, or do you have a different primary goal and are looking at this as well?

Comment: @Upper_Case Thanks for your comment. I'm interesting in comparing mean scores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that confidence intervals are what you want here. What I would do is set up the problem as follows:

1. Collect the response data for thing 1 and thing 2 (which you've done).
2. Set up my hypothesis test as follows:

   > Null hypothesis: Mean(thing 1) - Mean(thing 2) < 5
   >
   > Alternative hypothesis: Mean(thing 1) - Mean(thing 2) >= 5
3. Execute your chosen test (I'm assuming a two-sample t-test is what you would use)
4. Assess and interpret your test results at  your chosen confidence level (95%, in your case)

If the p-value from your t-test is greater than 0.05 you can say that, based on your sample and at a 95% confidence level, there is not sufficient evidence to conclude that the means of thing 1 and thing 2 differ by five or more.

This is not the same as saying that it is implausible that they do differ by that much, but rather that the evidence from your sample does not support the conclusion that they differ by that much.

Comment: how would I express the alternative hypothesis in a statistical analysis tool like Prism 7? Normally I just add the two columns of data and then run the test but I'm not sure how to set it up to test for a difference

Comment: Should I be looking at the mean of differences?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Prism 7, but I would be surprised if the documentation for it didn't list a way to perform a two-sample t-test with a difference in means.

Comment: It would be difference in means for a 2 sample t-test but the **mean of the differences** that I should be looking at in a paired test, right?

Comment: That sounds like a correct description of a paired t-test. But to be clear: as outlined in your question, this is not a scenario where a paired test is appropriate.

Comment: Have edited the post - it's now appropriate, yeah?

Comment: It might be, depending on what respondents are rating in your surveys. If respondents are rating the same thing in each survey, just at different times, then I would say yes. If the are rating different things I would say probably not. More context on your specific study would help.